# Say a preference is "constant“, by analogy with a constant function

Tags: microeconomics, preferences, decision-theory

Let $f$ be a function with range of $\{-1,1\}$ and $f(x,y)=-f(y,x)$.

Let the preference $\succ\subset X\times X$ where $x\succ y \iff f(x,y)=1$.

In math we can define $f$ to be a constant function on a subset $Y\times Z\subset X\times X$:

$f(Y\times Z)=-1 \ OR \ 1$.

In economics, without defining a function, is it standard to say that the preference is a "constant" at the subset?

For example: is it standard and clear to say "$\succ$ over $Y\times Z$ is the same", or, "for each $(y,z)\in Y\times Z$ the preference between $y$ and $z$ is the same"?

---

It is true that:

For each $y,z$ (the preference between $y,z$ is constant)

$\iff$ Either for each $y,z$: $y\succ z$, or for each $y,z$: $y\prec z$.

However, we still don't know what is equivalent to the proposition in bracket (the preference between $y,z$ is constant).

It is possible that the proposition itself is ill-defined. But since we often say that a function is constant, I don't think saying a preference is constant is wrong.

I think the proposition in bracket is equivalent to:

$\forall y',z': y\succ z \iff y'\succ z'$

(Of course, this assumes that $\succ=\not\prec$. And there is one further problem in this expression.)

Comment: I have never seen anything like that. You could simply write "Either every element of $X$ is preferred to ever element of $Y$ or every element of $Y$ is preferred to $X$."

Comment: Hi @MichaelGreinecker I agree that your supplied statement might be equivalent to "constant preference". However, note that the supplied statement is not a [Prenex normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form). I will include more details in the question.

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to write everything in prenex normal form?

Comment: Hi @MichaelGreinecker I updated the question and while writing I think a find a possible (albeit a bit complicated) answer.

Comment: If you really want everything in prenex normal form: $\forall x\forall y:(x\in X\wedge y\in Y~\implies~x\succ y)\vee(x\in X\wedge y\in Y~\implies~y\succ x)$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for your help, let me digest it a bit.